# AngularJS 1.5 component won't invoke $onChanges upon change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, components, angularjs-components

I have an AngularJS 1.5 component inside an html page (not parent component)
and the component won't invoke $onChanges upon change.

**HTML**

```
<my-comp standards-data="standardsData"></my-comp>
```

**Component**

```
angular.module("bla").component('myComp', {
    templateUrl: '/my-comp.tpl.html',
    controller: myController,
    bindings: {
        standardsData: '<'
    }
});

function myController() {
    var self = this;

    self.$onInit = function () {
        self.standardsData = {};
    }

    self.$onChanges = function (changes) {
        self.standardsData.something = changes.standardsData.currentValue.something;
    };
}
```

When I fetch new data in the ctrl of the html that contains my component,
it won't influence the component. I get only into the `$onInit` of the component
and after `$scope.standardsData` changes (in the containing html/ctrl),
the `$OnChanges` of my component won't invoke.

Hope I described the problem correctly,
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your component binding to `standardsData` is a binding to an object reference, which does not change even when one of its properties is modified.  As a result, `$onChanges` is not triggered.  This is due to the fact that `$onChanges` uses a shallow `$watch`.

In other words, `$onChanges` is triggered only if we use primitives (*i.e. non-objects*) or change the **reference** of the javascript object bound into the component

So, you need to either: 1) Bind manually to the property/properties you want, rather than the object reference, or 2) Change the entire `standardsData` object when its data changes.  *You could also 3) Rewrite `$onChanges` functionality, I suppose (not recommended)*.

**Option 1: Bind only to the property**

Use if the parent controller/component merely changes a property or properties.

```
<my-comp standards-data-something="standardsData.something"></my-comp>
```

and

```
bindings: {
    standardsDataSomething: '<'
}
```

**Option 2: Change the reference**

Use if the parent controller/component obtains completely new `standardsData`.  You would keep your current HTML for this option and set:

```
standardsData = {newData};  //Reset the new data from http or wherever
```

to change the reference.

---

Some further reading you may find interesting:

http://blog.kwintenp.com/the-onchanges-lifecycle-hook/

http://www.codelord.net/2016/12/20/replacing-angulars-deep-watches-with-the-%24docheck-lifecycle-hook/

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
Actually I don't think it's because standardsData is an object.

There are 2 cases in the application:

1. We click on some link and routing into this screen. When doing so, 
there is no activity in the onChanges event. (only onInit)...

2. On that point, when I refresh the page (like F5), the onChanges 
event starts to get into action.


any idea ?
Thanks !

Comment: @moshi - Two things cause `$onChanges` to fire:  1) When the component first initializes, 2) when changes are made to a binding by the parent.  The F5 refresh causes you to see change activity from initialization.  You never see it again because you have bound to an object reference that doesn't change.  I will delete my (correct) answer if you like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I agree with you that $onChanges occurs upon initialization.
I don't see that it always occurs upon data changes.
It's like when I refresh the page and click on the menu items
(which each one of them loads new data for that component) - every 
thing goes fine. For each click - the $onChanges happens.

BUT - when I go to another page and click there on a link to my page 
(the page that contains the component), my component $onChanges 
won't fire although I refresh the data. 

Then, no matter any menu click I do - it won't cause $onChanges on my component.

Comment: BTW - regarding the object reference issue, before loading the data into 
$scope.standardsData , I tried also to do : 
$scope.standardsData = null
$scope.standardsData  = new Object.....

There's no change.

BTW - I liked your answer and I don't have any problem to mark as an answer.
Thanks again :-)

Comment: Another page?  It sounds like you have some major issues with the design of your app and the problem is probably not related to `$onChanges` at all.  I can't help you further without seeing the entire app.  No need to mark as the answer if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, another html template, related to the controller. the component I speak on is located inside another html template. All inside the index of course, it is a SPA.